# How can I mine ethereum with several PCs?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, geth

I'm trying to mine ethereum with geth. I want to use 2 windows PCs for mining. First off, I don't know how to connect ethereum public network with the same account from these 2 PCs. What I did is as follows.

I connected ethereum public network with geth from PC1.

```
geth --datadir "public" --syncmode fast --cache 2048 console 2>> public/e01.log
```

Then I made an account on PC1.

```
personal.newAccount("password")
```

But I don't know how to "login" this account from PC2. I searched a command of "login account", but I couldn't find it. How can I connect the same account from different PCs?

Second, it seems that I lose what I mined when I close geth. I started mining.

```
miner.start()
```

Then I checked I made some blocks.

```
eth.blockNumber
```

But after I reboot geth, I found that the block I made was gone. I thought the result of the mining is stored on the public network, but it isn't?

Sorry for this naive question, but please tell me what I missed.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the high difficulty, you can not mine blocks with your cpu on the public ethereum net. If you have a GPU, you can join a mining pool (e.g. https://ethermine.org/)

If you want to create your own testnet on which you want to mine (for testing purposes), you can follow this guide: https://medium.com/coinbundle/how-do-i-set-up-my-own-ethereum-testnet-cebab790c696